# What is this Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis

What is the definition or theorem  used to proof this problem in line 5. where it says there would exist a e$>$0 such that $\mid$x-c$\mid$ $<$e and x$\in$[a,b] implies $\mid$f(x)-f(c)$\mid$ $<$ 1/2$\mid$f(c)$\mid$.

Question -  Let f be a continuous function whose domain includes the closed interval [a,b]. If f(a)$<$0 and f(b)$>$0, then there is a number x between a and b such that f(x)=0.

1. Let f be a continuous function whose domain includes the closed interval [a,b]
2. Let f(a)$<$0 and f(b)$>$0.
3. Let the set M=$\{x$\in[a,b]$\mid$f(x)$<$0$\}$ exist and c$\in$M.
4. Then a$\in$M and M is bounded from above by b.
5. Then suppose that f(c)$\neq$0. So f would be continuous at c, and there would exist a e$>$0 such that $\mid$x-c$\mid$ $<$e and x$\in$[a,b] implies $\mid$f(x)-f(c)$\mid$ $<$ 1/2$\mid$f(c)$\mid$.

Case 1. f(c)$<$0

6. Let f(c)$<$0.
7. Then f(x)=f(c)+f(x)-f(c)$<$f(c)-1/2f(c) for all x$\in[a,b]$ such that $\mid$x-c$\mid$ $<$e.
8. So f(x)$<$1/2f(c)$<$0 which means there are points x$\in$M with x$>$c which would contradict c being the upper bound of M.

Case 2. f(c)$>$0

9. Let f(c)$>$0.
10. Then f(x)=f(c)+f(x)-f(c)$>$f(c)-1/2f(c) for all x$\in[a,b]$ such that $\mid$x-c$\mid$ $<$e.
11. So f(x)$>$1/2f(c)$>$0.
12. Then there exists a n$>$o such that c-n$\geq$a and f(x)$>$0 and c-n$\geq$x$\geq$c.
13. So when c-n$<$c it would be an upper bound for M.
14. Since c is a upper bound and f(x)$>$0 for c-n$\geq$x$\geq$c which is a contradiction to c being the least upper bound.
15. Thus, f(c)=0 and c$\neq$a,b since f is nonzero at the endpoints and a$<$c$<$b.
16. Therefore, Let f be a continuous function whose domain includes the closed interval [a,b]. If f(a)$<$0 and f(b)$>$0, then there is a number x between a and b such that f(x)=0.

Comment: This is the definition of continuity applied with $\varepsilon = |f(c)|/2$.

Comment: but why is 1/2 used